# Why i can't get select index of listbox in VB

Tags: vb.net, listbox

When I add items to list box by collection items in properties, I can get selected index. But when I add items by coding, I can't get selected index. Data (added by coding) is from data table parameter.

```
Dim test As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
```

That I used this code to get select index.

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString & "_" & dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString & "g")
```

This code is adding items.

Comment: SelectedIndex was meant to tell you what item the *user* selected.  Does not have anything to do with adding items in your code.  If you want to know the index of the item you just added then simply use the return value of the Add() method.

Comment: I'm sorry I tell you not clear. I wanted to get user selected . When I selected item and click button to run code to get selected index , I always get -1. I can use every functions of listbox except select function ( selectedindex, selectedvalue, ......... ).

Comment: If you are building your ListBox in the same code as the one in which you are trying to get the selected index, it means you destroy the object that existed before and create a new one instead. In which case there is NO selected index (and you get -1). 
Please provide a MWE (Minimum Working Exemple) so that we can see the problem in context in order to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this if this is what you mean

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Label1.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem
End Sub
```

returns the text

and this...

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Label1.Text = ListBox1.GetItemText(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
End Sub
```

returns the index